# Loop through elements in Div gets first Element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to loop through ALL elements in `MainDiv` Div to get their values  but the problem is i get the first element only

```
<div id="MainDiv">
    <input type="text" id="MyText"value="Text1" />
    <input type="text" id="MyText1" value="Text2" />

    <textarea id="Textarea1">A</textarea>
    <textarea id="Textarea2">B</textarea>
</div>


  $('#MainDiv').each(function () {

            var Value1 = $(this).find("input[type = 'text'][id^='MyText']").val();
            alert(Value1);

            var Value2 = $(this).find("[id^='Textarea']").val();
            alert(Value2);

        })
```

Comment: there is only 1 main div

Comment: You need `$('#MainDiv').children().each()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JQuery as a plugin, to get each field value just have to modify the line bellow, following the example given by NKHIL CM.

```
$('#MainDiv').find("*").each(function (key, elem) {
  console.log(elem.value);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `#MainDiv` at HTML `.each()` will iterate exactly once.

You can use attribute contains selector with value set to `"Text"` to iterate all descendant elements of `#MainDiv` where `id` contains `"Text"`

```
$("#MainDiv [id*=Text]").each(function() {
  console.log(this.value) // do stuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example, to select input, textarea, select from specific division

If you can put name attribute, and then want to access in array its better to use

```
$('#MainDiv').find('input, select, textarea').serializeArray();
```

```js
$('#MainDiv').find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){  
  console.log(this.id +'=>'+$(this).val());
});

// if you can put name attribute
console.log( $('#MainDiv').find('input, select, textarea').serializeArray() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MainDiv">
    <input type="text" id="MyText"value="Text1" />
    <input type="text" id="MyText1" value="Text2" />

    <textarea id="Textarea1">A</textarea>
    <textarea id="Textarea2">B</textarea>

    <!-- if you can put name attribute -->
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="for_serialize" value="test me"/>
    <input type="text" id="t2" name="for_serialize2" value="test me2"/>
</div>
```

Comment: 3161993,Thank you for your help and effort :)
I tried your code it  works but i have to push these elements values in an array that why i want   Text1,A and then Text2,B

Comment: you can create array before `each` loop like, `var myarray=[]`, and then inside loop `myarray.push( { this.id : $(this).val() } )`, if you can set name attribute, its easy to use `serializeArray()`, I hope you have seen it

Answer (score 0):

If You want to iterate through every element inside a div you could use "*" selector with find method in JQuery.

```js
  $('#MainDiv').find("*").each(function (elem) {
          console.log(elem)
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MainDiv">
    <input type="text" id="MyText"value="Text1" />
    <input type="text" id="MyText1" value="Text2" />

    <textarea id="Textarea1">A</textarea>
    <textarea id="Textarea2">B</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: NIKHIL C M, Thank you for your help and effort :) 

Your code looks like it will be working but Can you please show me how can i get the value of each element
Thank you